# How much security does using TLS provide?

Tags: tls, transport-security

If someone tells me their service uses TLS 1.2 or higher, how much 'guaranteed' security does this provide?

Is it possible to correctly claim to be using TLS 1.2 or 1.3 and still be insecure? For example, using a correctly implimented TLS handshake but with a weak cipher?

If it is possible to 'correctly' impliment TLS insecurly, using the above example, what would be examples of ciphers that are acceptable in the TLS standards but are actually insecure?

Comment: You might want to ask this on [security.se].

Comment: TLS 1.2 supports the cipher suite TLS_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL which provides no confidentiality, integrity  nor authentication. Arguably it is meeting its security claims though.

Comment: [ERR- CROSS POSTED !!!](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/248835/86735)

Comment: @kelalaka posted to information security after forest comment. Both have different but informative answers...

Comment: It doesn't matter! One should never do that. Forest's comment was dense, and it includes deleting your question.

Comment: @kelalaka Can't the two questions be merged to Security.SE by a mod?

Comment: @DanielShiu: all-null is used only during the handshake (and only the first, not any renegotiation). <=1.2 application data can have null _encryption_ but must have HMAC, and in practice must have authentication (technically it _could_ work with 'anonymous' but no registered ciphersuites do so).

Comment: @forest don't know. maybe a migrate than merge?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to correctly claim to be using TLS 1.2 or 1.3 and still be insecure?

Absolutely.  Even discounting deliberate attempts to be insecure, an implementation could have an implementation error that would:

- Select their premaster secret (for TLS 1.2 RSA-based ciphersuites) with poor entropy
- Select their (EC)DH private values with poor entropy
- Select their CBC or GCM IVs poorly
- Not properly validating the certificate

> what would be examples of ciphers that are acceptable in the TLS standards but are actually insecure?

TLS 1.2 has a number of 'not-very-secure' ciphersuites (as it inherited all of the TLS 1.0 ciphersuites).  In TLS 1.3, they reduced the number of supported ciphersuites to 5, none of which are horrid (I'm not thrilled with the CCM_8 based one, but even that isn't that bad).

On the other hand, even in TLS 1.2, both sides would have to agree to use a 'not-very-secure' ciphersuite; for the possible implementation flaws I listed above, the other side would have no good way of checking on them.

Comment: CCM_8 still provides a forgery probability of $2^{-64}$, which is not bad for a MAC.

Comment: @forest: as I said, "that isn't that bad"